# Selecting non-unique field from table where data does not contain string

Tags: sql, oracle, select

First, this is what the tables look like:

```
Checkpoint
==========
trans_id
checkpoint_id

Checkpoint_Data
===============
checkpoint_id
data
```

`trans_id` is not unique for `checkpoint`. `checkpoint_id` is unique for `checkpoint` as well as `checkpoint_data`. `Checkpoint_id` links `checkpoint` and `checkpoint_data`

I want to select all the `trans_id` from `checkpoint` where the associated `data` from `checkpoint_data` does NOT contain some string.

I essentially want to invert this statement:

```
SELECT ch.trans_id
FROM   checkpoint ch,
       checkpoint_data chd
WHERE  ch.checkpoint_id = chd.checkpoint_id
     AND Upper(chd.data)LIKE Upper('%Example String%')
```

A simple NOT LIKE did not work.

Comment: you want `NOT LIKE` but you are using `LIKE`. TRY `Upper(chd.data) NOT LIKE Upper('%Example String%')`

Comment: Using NOT does not work. A trans_id links several checkpoints, and data together. Even if a checkpoint does not have 'Example String' it is most likely that one of the other checkpoints has it, and that trans_id will still be returned by the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or something like this...

```
SELECT ch.trans_id
FROM   checkpoint ch
except
SELECT ch.trans_id
FROM   checkpoint ch,
   checkpoint_data chd
WHERE  ch.checkpoint_id = chd.checkpoint_id
 AND Upper(chd.data)LIKE Upper('%Example String%')
```

Comment: I'm getting errors when I try to run this. "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" when I run it directly, "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" when I run it through a JDBC driver

Comment: @user906153:Use MINUS in oracle instead of EXCEPT(SQL SERVER Syntax)

Comment: ty @Gaurav... and sorry, user906153.. didnt see the oracle tag and did wrote for sql server

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
SELECT ch.trans_id
FROM   checkpoint ch
WHERE not exists ( select * from checkpoint_data chd
                   where ch.checkpoint_id = chd.checkpoint_id 
                   AND Upper(chd.data) LIKE Upper('%Example String%')
                  )
```

Comment: This did not return the desired results, unfortunately